# Connecting a website to a database

Tags: php, sql, database, azure, web

I am sorry if this is the wrong stack exchange, if so please redirect me.

I am very much in doubt about how I go about the following, and I can't really seem to google my way to a solution, so here goes:

Let's say I have a website which basically only consists of a search bar, which I want to link up to a database which every user can search in. In addition to this I want to be the only one who can actually add new data to this database.

To do this, would I basically "just" buy a website domain, make some SQL query hookup to a database that I rent from fx Microsoft Azure? Then whenever people would search for a string the website would query the database and return any relevant information.

Is this the correct way to go about this issue?

Comment: You're gonna need hosting as well as the domain and database. Use PHP for the SQL queries, based on data sent by a post request from a HTML form. See here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Okay so I don't need to use SQLlite language or anything? Just regular old PHP to code the search bar? Is this possible to do via wordpress or would I have to code things from scratch?

Comment: It's up to you. Personally I'd use php, there are plenty of tutorials on how to link with a database. A simple html form for search bar, post request to the same page, query the search string with the database, return results.

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, I would suggest you use Azure App Service MySQL in-app, which has a cool feature for Web developers to create Web applications that use MySQL. You don’t need to provision a database explicitly as during the creation of the web app when using this feature.

For more details, please refer to [Announcing MySQL in-app for Web Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/08/18/announcing-mysql-in-app-preview-for-web-apps/) and [Create a PHP web app in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-php).